# Action method not invoked when form is resubmitted from Jquery callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-2

I am using JSF/Javascript/Jquery to build a creditcard payment form using Stripe. Following is the code:

**JSF Form**

```
<h:form id="payment-form">
:
    :
    Input text fields
    :                       
    <h:commandButton id="submitBtn" value="Submit Payment" styleClass="button round blue" action="#{userBean.submitPayment}">
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

The submit event handler in Jquery is as follows -

```
function stripeResponseHandler(){
    alert("in responseHandler");

    var f = $("#payment-form");
// Token contains id, last4, and card type:
var token = response['id'];

    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
      f.append("<input type='hidden' name='stripeToken' value='" + token + "' />");

// re-enable the submit button
    $("#payment-form\\:submitBtn").attr("disabled", false);

// Submit the form
    //$("#payment-form")[0].submit();
    return false;
}

function reportError(msg) {
    // Show the error in the form:
    $('#payment-errors').text(msg).addClass('alert alert-error');
    // re-enable the submit button:
    $("#payment-form\\:submitBtn").prop('disabled', false);
    return false;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#payment-form").submit(function(event) {
        alert("in eventHandler");

        // Flag variable:
        var error = false;

        // disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks:
        $("#payment-form\\:submitBtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");

        // Get the values:
        // Validate the fields
        // Validate other form elements, if needed!

        // Check for errors:
        if (!error) {
            //alert("Getting the token");
            // Get the Stripe token:
            Stripe.card.createToken({
                number: ccNum,
                cvc: cvcNum,
                exp_month: expMonth,
                exp_year: expYear
            }, stripeResponseHandler);

        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

(Code taken from Stripe to integrate with JSF form)

The above code does not invoke the backing bean method mentioned in the action parameter of the h:commandButton when it is called from stripeResponseHandler, which is a callback for the asynchronous response from Stripe.

Can someone please shed light on what is wrong in the above code.

Comment: @BalusC - Thanks for the response, but that question did not answer and did not work in this case. The disable actually happens after control passes to the event handler and is reenabled before the resubmit happens. The above code works if stripeResponsehandler is called synchronously (immediately after event.preventDefault), but does not work in the async callback situation.

Comment: The above code is suggested by Stripe for regular html forms in association with php, java etc.. but it does not work with JSF. Any specific reason?